# Is it possible to typeset the Ge'ez alphabet in LaTeX?

Tags: languages, linguistics, alphabet

Is there any package for typesetting [Ge'ez (Ethiopic)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ge%27ez_script) in LaTeX?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I am not sure, but there is a `ethiop` package.

Comment: You can use the Unicode input if charsets are defined for a specific font.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the documentation of `ethiop` package, I used a line, but I have no idea whether this is a correct form. Just compile with `pdflatex`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ethiop]{babel}
\usepackage{ethiop} % only needed for older TeX distributions

\begin{document}

'abAs : 'alamenahe

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit** I don't know whether this is 'Ge'ez' at all...

Comment: That is Geez @Christian Hupfer.But it doesn't work on my WinEdt. any help?

Comment: @marana: You need to have a proper TeX distribution (i.e.) a new one, such as TeXlive 2014 or MikTeX

Comment: So @Christian Hupfer Could you tell me where could i get it?

Comment: @marana: I don't use Windows and WinEdt, but try to install MikTeX from http://miktex.org/download

Comment: @marana: You can download MiKTeX from this place: http://miktex.org/download. For TeX Live, you can go there: http://www.tug.org/texlive/acquire-netinstall.html.

Answer (score 11):

Gəʿəz can be beautifully typeset using [XeLaTeX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XeLaTeX) ([xelatex](/questions/tagged/xelatex)) and [`fontspec`](https://github.com/wspr/fontspec/) ([fontspec](/questions/tagged/fontspec)), which support all kinds of complex scripts and advanced font abilities. As far as I know, this should be possible in a very similar way with [LuaLaTeX](http://luatex.org/) ([lualatex](/questions/tagged/lualatex)) and `fontspec`, but I’m not familiar with Lua(La)TeX.

Here is an example; it uses free ([OFL](http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?site_id=nrsi&id=OFL#3b878279)) fonts — [Abyssinica SIL](http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?item_id=AbyssinicaSIL) for Gəʿəz script and [Gentium](http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?site_id=nrsi&item_id=Gentium) for Latin script — but you can use any Unicode font you wish.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\begin{document}

\fontspec{Abyssinica SIL}
ቃለ፡ በረከት፡ ዘሄኖክ፡ ዘከመ፡ ባረከ፡ ኅሩያነ፡ ወጻድቃነ፡ እለ፡ ሀለዉ፡ ይኩኑ፡\\
በዕለተ፡ ምንዳቤ፡ ለአሰስሎ፡ ኵሉ፡ እኩያን፡ ወረሲዓን።

\fontspec{Gentium}
Ḳāla barakat za-Henok zakama bāraka ḫəruyāna waṣādəḳāna ʾəlla hallawu yəkunu\\
baʿəlata məndābe laʾasassəlo kʷəllu ʾəkuyān warasiʿān

\end{document}
```

[image: The first sentence from the Book of Enoch]

This has some advantages over using the [`ethiop`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/ethiop) package:

- It does not depend on a specific package for a specific script, but uses a generic way of typesetting scripts from around the world.
- Moreover, the input is [Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) ([unicode](/questions/tagged/unicode)). Unicode has many advantages derived from being a worldwide accepted standard; for example, you can collaborate with anyone writing in Gəʿəz script and can be sure your text will be accessible, technically, for many years to come in a simple and easy way.

Comment: @Mico: What are you on about? This answer is really nice, and I cannot find any harshness.

Comment: @morbusg: It's harsh in the sense that at the moment of writing my solution there was no information on `XeLaTeX` or `pdflatex`, so it was/is a working solution. I appreciate other solutions as well, of course

Comment: @Mico, I have no ill will here, but it is interesting to note how different people read the "mood" behind written text. I personally do strongly agree with the second point; user having to use some cryptic ASCII representation of his/her script somehow rubs me the wrong way. And sure, it might have been the only way to get the job done 18 years ago. But now we do have the **correct** tools for this (correct in the sense of user input), which I feel we, as a community, are not promoting enough. Christian, please don't take this the wrong way, I don't mean to diminish your answer.

Comment: I’ve rephrased it; I hope it is better now. No impoliteness nor any kind of ill will were intended. I’m sorry if anyone was offended by my previous phrasing, which was merely intended as a dialogical way of communication: deriving the starting point of the answer from a previously answered one, offering what I deem a better, modern solution.

Comment: @Miko: It *is* specific in the sense that it is a specific package for a specific script. My solution does not depend on a specific font (you can easily replace Abyssinica SIL by any other Unicode font supporting Gəʿəz, which as far as I understand cannot be said on changing the font in `ethiop`), nor it depends on a specific engine (you can use LuaLaTeX as well). It does depend on `fontspec` for font selection, but `fontspec` isn’t tailored for a specific font and theoretically can be easily replaced by another package for font selection without any modification of the input.

Comment: It should have been ‘@Mico’; sorry.

Comment: Many thanks for rephrasing your answer. I've removed my earlier comments.